# Printing on Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, console

I am newbie to android. I am working on a project wherein I need to give directional info on the android mobile. So, I have to see directional messages on my android screen. I had written the code in normal java and compiled, executed on Command prompt. I was able to see the output of the print statements which I had given in my code. So, I created a new android project and then created another class and pasted my code there. To my surprise, I don't find the print statements on the emulator screen. Moreover, when I tried to do the same last evening, I was able to see the print statements on the console window of eclipse. But I don't see the same now. Can you please explain how to make my print statements appear on the emulator screen. At the same time, pls let me know why I was able to see those print statements on the console window of eclipse and what should I do to replicate the same? I can see only Hello World on the emulator screen.

Below is the piece of code:

`package com.example.visual;

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.restlet.data.ChallengeScheme;
import org.restlet.ext.json.JsonRepresentation;
import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ItsClient4 extends Activity {

private final static String BASE_URL = "my website url";
private final static String SITE_ID = "67";// Your site ID here
private final static String STATION_MAC[] = {"mac1","mac2"};// The station's MAC address
private final static String NODES[] = {"mac3","mac4","mac5","mac6","mac7","mac8"};
private final static String USERNAME = "usrname";// Your username
private final static String PASSWORD = "pwd";// Your password
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// Set the request parameters
while(true){
double c[]=new double[6];
double d[]=new double[6];
String url[] =new String[2];
ClientResource itsClient[] = new ClientResource[2];
JsonRepresentation jsonRep[] = new JsonRepresentation[2];
for(int i=0;i<=0;i++){

url[i] = BASE_URL + "sites/" + SITE_ID + "/stations/"+ STATION_MAC[i] + "/";

itsClient[i] = new ClientResource(url[i]);
                 itsClient[i].setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
// Retrieve and parse the JSON representation
jsonRep[i] = new JsonRepresentation(itsClient[i].get());
JSONObject jsonObj = jsonRep[i].getJsonObject();
// Output results

c[i]=jsonObj.getJSONObject("loc").getDouble("lat");
d[i]=jsonObj.getJSONObject("loc").getDouble("lng");

Toast.makeText(ItsClient4.this,"text",20000).show();
//Toast.makeText(ItsClient4.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
System.out.println(c[i] +" "+d[i]);
if(d[i]>78.142182){
System.out.println("near E8");
}
}


}
}
}
```

`

Pls check the above code and pls help me how to use Toast. Its still giving me the error "cannot use this in a static context". In my package "visual", in the src directory, com.example.visual has two sub-directories. One is the MainActivity.java and the other is ItsClient4.java. MainActivity.java is automatically created one.I have created ItsClient4.java by adding a new Class in the com.example.visual directory. Pls tell me how to overcome the above error.

Can't I use the Toast inside Main function?

Comment: 1. `for(int i=0;i<=0;i++)` ends at the end of the code? i fixed the format but its missing 2. what's the reason of using a for statement? This code just runs for `i=0`

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please explain how to make my print statements appear on the emulator screen.

Use `Toast` to show the text on emulator.

Like

```
Toast.makeText(this, "text", Toast.LENGH_LONG).show();
```

You should use `logcat` like

```
Log.v("app","text"); and see this in logcat
```

This is better option for debugging also.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? How can I use Toast for my code which is listed above? I am newbie to android.

Comment: @user1473912 Use `log` instead of `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 0):

for print you can use Toast 
exanple:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Its throwing error when I use the above statement in my code. Do I need to create a separate class for the same? Or can I include the Toast syntax in my code directly. It would be great if u let me know the usage of the same.

Comment: import android.widget.Toast; just add this

Comment: MainActivity.this ->  MainActivity is the class name right??? Since my class is ItsClient4, I have used ItsClient4.this, my msg, integer value

Comment: MainActivity is your activity class then msg then a integer

Answer (score 0):

Like TGMCians says, a `Toast` will do the trick.

If you want to write it to the LogCat instead, then you can use

```
Log.i(tag, message)
```

You can then view this in the LogCat in Eclipse by going to Window > Show View > Other > Android > LogCat

Comment: With later versions of the Android SDK standard Java prints will also appear in the logcat

Comment: In my application, those directional messages has to be displayed on the emulator screen. I am not using those messages for debugging purpose. Why don't the normal System.out.Println doesn't print the message in emulator?

Comment: "Why don't the normal System.out.Println doesn't print the message in emulator?" Because android is a GUI, not a command-line OS.

Comment: I am getting the below errors: How to resolve them                     Cannot use this in a static context                                           
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (ItsClient4, String, int)

Comment: Toast.makeText(Visual.this, "text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show();              Is this correct???

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to get feedback on android.

**SOLUTION 1:**

An Activity to just show feedback on screen.
Change your on create like the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a string with text
    String message = "the text you want to show";

    // here you can write / change your 'message' to 
    //         whatever you want to display on screen...

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);

    // enable textView to scroll to for long text to be visible
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); 

    // add the text to the textview
    textView.setText(message); 

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

A [Toast messages](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) lasts for sort time period, and pop-up at the bottom (by default) of the screen:

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

- context:   `this` if code is in Activity class
- text:      usually a string
- duration:  `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`

**SOLUTION 3:**

A log message.
It is similar to java code `System.out.println("a message");` this code although it works it is not commonplace to see it written. Instead we use android native [Log class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

```
Log.v(TAG, "your message here" + and_some_other_variable);
```

- TAG: a string in order to find easier your logs, can be used for filtering.

More info about debugging logs [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).